# Deploying Laravel 4 with Capistrano. Permission denied during `composer install`

Tags: permissions, laravel, capistrano, composer-php

I'm trying to use Capistrano to deploy my Laravel 4 site and when I try to:

```
run "cd #{current_path} && composer install --no-dev"`
```

in my `deploy.rb` I get this error:

```
sh: 1: composer: Permission denied
```

and a few lines later:

```
failed: "sh -c 'cd /var/www/public/mysite/current && composer install --no-dev'" on root@my.ip.add.ress
```

If I comment out the `run` command above then Capistrano is able to complete the deployment successfully. However, I then have to manually run `composer install` from the `current` release directory of my site in order to get everything on my site working properly.

I've tried running my deploy with the `-d` flag to go through the deployment step by step, I've tried fixing permissions in case they were incorrect, but neither seems to fix this error. Also, I've looked all over for a possible answer and can't find anyone else with this specific issue.

**So, I have two questions:**

1. Any ideas of a fix to this?
2. It seems like running `composer install` each time I deploy is just creating more work than is necessary. Would it be better to either:

   a) not ignore the `vendor` folder`in my local repository therefore removing the need to run`composer install` on each deploy? Or,

   b) run `composer install` in the root directory (at the same directory level as `current` and `releases`) and then change the path to `vendor/autoload.php` in the `bootstrap` directory to point to this new directory so I never need to run `composer install` again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Instead of:

```
run "cd #{current_path} && composer install --no-dev"
```

I'm doing this instead:

```
run "cd #{releases_path}/#{release_name} && php /usr/local/bin/composer/composer.phar install --no-dev"
```

(I changed `#{current_path}` to `#{releases_path}/#{release_name}` because Capistrano was executing `rm -f /var/www/public/myapp/current` AFTER the `composer install` command.